# Current year in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

How can I get current year in Ruby on Rails?

I tried a variety of things, including

- Date.current.year
- Time.now.year

The problem is they return the previous year in cases where year changes after launching the server (eg. after new year's).

Relevant code:

Model brewery.rb

```
class Brewery < ActiveRecord: :Base
...
validates :year, numericality: { only_integer: true, less_than_or_equal_to: Date.today.year }
...
```

Problem occurs when creating a new brewery, so I assumed Date.today.year would be evaluated whenever that action takes place.

Comment: Do you need it in an ActiveRecord scope, by any chance?

Comment: They return the current date / time. Maybe it's a caching issue or you're using Timecop in your production code?

Comment: @art-solopov yes, I need it in an ActiveRecord

Comment: @AtteJuvonen Can we see the code please?

Comment: `Time.now.year` will *always* return the current year, unless you've messed with the classes directly or through a gem. If you're *storing* the value somewhere that's completely different.

Comment: @DaveNewton This kinda looks like a case of incorrectly defined scope. That's why I asked for the code.

Comment: Added code into original question

Comment: This evaluates the year a single time, at class load.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your example, `Date.today.year` is evaluated only once when the application is started and the class is loaded and therefore doesn't change any more later on.

But when you use a lambda in your validator declaration, then the lambda is evaluated each time when the validation is checked for that attribute:

```
validates :year, numericality: { 
  only_integer: true, 
  less_than_or_equal_to: ->(_brewery) { Date.current.year }
}
```

Furthermore, I suggest using `Date.current` instead of `Date.today` because the `current` method pays attention to timezone settings.

Answer (score 18):

`<%= Time.zone.now.year %>` -- factors in time zone

Answer (score 4):

[@spickermann's recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35228046/4575793) seems to be correct, I'll just try to explain why it works.

The code you write inside your class is executed at compile time, when Ruby compiles to the VM bytecode. Therefore, the `Date.today.year` in your validator is calculated exactly once, when the class is compiled.

By introducing the lambda you enable ActiveRecord to use the return value of said lambda. The lambda itself will be executed with each validation.

Hope that made the situation clearer!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it's better to use `Time.current` instead of `Time.now` in Rails, because the first one adopts current time zone. [Find the ROR Guides here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#time-current).